# Nested For loop to iterate records in PLSQL

Tags: plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, plsqldeveloper

I am trying to iterate through records using nested for loop, Idea is to compare all the records in the record array with the next element to check for date intersection. 
My question is what to fill in the below code in place of XXXXXXXX. As mentioned, the idea is to start comparing the first record with every other record (using second for loop). Thanks in advance.

```
 FOR i IN rx_records.first.. rx_records.last
        LOOP
         FOR j IN XXXXXXXX.. rx_records.last
        LOOP
        IF rx_records(i).eff_startdate <= rx_records(j).eff_enddate AND    rx_records(i).eff_enddate   >= rx_records(j).eff_startdate
        THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('00'); 
        ELSE
        dbms_output.Put_line('11'); 


        END IF;

        END LOOP;

     END LOOP;
```

END;

Comment: You can simply set there rx_records.first to compare the first row with the first row in the beginning or rx_records.first + 1 to skip comparing first row with itself. The performance of such comparison will be really poor, though.

Why do you need to compare those values? Maybe there is a better way to compare them?

Comment: If you have a set of rows in a table and you want to check for overlapping values, there are easier ways than this.

Answer (score 1):

I think the following example should meet your requirements (although, such operations on tables are really ineffective regarding performance):

```
IF rx_records.COUNT > 1 THEN
    FOR i IN rx_records.FIRST .. rx_records.LAST
    LOOP
        FOR j IN rx_records.FIRST + 1 .. rx_records.LAST
        LOOP
            IF rx_records(i).eff_startdate <= rx_records(j).eff_enddate AND rx_records(i).eff_enddate >= rx_records(j).eff_startdate THEN
                DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('00');
            ELSE
                DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('11');
            END IF;
        END LOOP;
    END LOOP;
ELSIF rx_records.COUNT = 1 THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('There''s only 1 row in the table. - nothing to compare it to');
ELSE
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('There are no rows in the table.');
END IF;
```